# SQL Selecting all but newest result per id

Tags: sql-server

I need to set a "waived" flag in my table for all but the newest result per id. I thought I had a query that will work here, but when I run a select on the query, I'm getting incorrect results - I saw one case where it selected both of the only two results for a particular id. I'm also getting multiple results with the same exact data.
What am I doing wrong here?

Here's my select statement:

```
select t.test_row_id, t.test_result_id, t.waived, t.pass, t.comment
from EV.Test_Result
join EV.Test_Result as t on EV.Test_Result.test_row_id = t.test_row_id and EV.Test_Result.start_time < t.start_time and t.device_id = 1219 and t.waived = 0
order by t.test_row_id
```

Here's the actual query I want to run:

```
update EV.Test_Result 
set waived = 1
from EV.Test_Result
join EV.Test_Result as t on EV.Test_Result.test_row_id = t.test_row_id and EV.Test_Result.start_time < t.start_time and t.device_id = 1219 and t.waived = 0
```

Comment: If you have a date column that returns a unique time stamp (meaning it is at least datetime), then this is easy with a MAX function. However, if not...well, maybe a design flaw in your table structure.

Comment: We do have a start_time column that is a datetime2. I've also tried max but had trouble getting that written correctly. Do you have an example? I'm not very proficient at SQL, this is not my main job description (though I'm trying to learn!).

Comment: One last suggestion would be formatting the query with indentations. SQL ignores inline spaces that are not in a string ('THIS IS A STRING IN SQL') (note ( ' ) is the string delimiter in SQL)

Comment: I was a moron and failed to proofread my alteration of the query from SO's environment. See my update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand this correctly, you are having problems because the Cardinality of the `ON` predicate returns all matching rows.

```
       EV.Test_Result.test_row_id = t.test_row_id 
   and EV.Test_Result.start_time < t.start_time
```

This `ON` will compare all of the start_time values that have the same id and return **every combination** of result sets where start_time is lesser than the t.start_time. Clearly, this is not what you want.

```
                    and t.device_id = 1219 
                    and t.waived = 0
```

This is actually a predicate (`ON` technically is one), but I would prefer to use this in a `subquery`/`CTE` for several reasons: You limit the number of rows `SQL` has to retrieve and compare.

Something like the following might be what you needed:

```
SELECT A.test_row_id
     , A.test_result_id
     , A.waived
     , A.pass
     , A.comment
FROM EV.Test_Result A
INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(start_time) AS start_time
                 , test_row_id
            FROM EV.Test_Result
            WHERE device_id = 1219
              AND waived = 0
            GROUP BY test_row_id
                            ) AS T ON A.test_row_id = T.test_row_id
                                  AND A.start_time < T.start_time
ORDER BY A.test_row_id
```

This query then returns a `1:M` relationship between the values in the `ON` predicate, unlike the `M:M` query you had run.

**UPDATE:**
Since I sheepishly screwed up trying to alter my Query on `SO`, I'll redeem myself by explaining the physical and logical orders of basic `SQL` Query operators:

As you know, you write a simple `SELECT` statement like the following:

```
SELECT <aggregate column>, SUM(<non-aggregate column>) AS Cost
FROM  <table_name>
WHERE <column> = 'some_value'
GROUP BY <aggregate column>
HAVING SUM(<non-aggregate column>) > some_value
ORDER BY <column>
```

Note that if you use a aggregate function, all other columns MUST appear in the GROUP BY or another function.

Now, SQL Server requires them to be written in that order although it actually processes this logically by the following order that is worth memorizing:

- FROM, WHERE, GROUP BY, HAVING, SELECT, ORDER BY

There are more details found on [SELECT - MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx), but this is why any columns in the `SELECT` operator must be in the group by or in a aggregate function (`SUM`, `MIN`, `MAX`, etc)...and also why my lazy code failed on your first attempt. :/
Note also that the `ORDER BY` is last (technically `TOP` operator occurs after this), and that without it the result is not deterministic unless a function such as `DENSE_RANK` enforces it (thought this occurs in the `SELECT` statement).

Hope this helps solve the problem and better yet how SQL works. Cheers

Comment: oops, forgot to specify the test_row_id in that subquery. xD

Comment: Thanks for this very informative answer, it helps to understand a bit better what is going on.
I tried your code and did get syntax errors near the WHERE in the subquery though. Any idea what is wrong there?

Comment: @Johonn LOL...xD yes... xD WHERE clause is put wrong. xD I need to remember to alter my queries less on SO. xD

Comment: Thanks! That worked pretty well. I did have to add

AND A.waived = 0
AND A.device_id = 1219

right before the ORDER statement.
Edit: don't know how to format code in a comment...

Comment: @johonn Yeah, I didn't know the details of your table, and i think the issue is on my end, still. The dates are creating a small cartesean. Likely the problem is with that extra ON predicate with the right inner query. If the ID is unique and nothing else can make the query unique to the join, it should be `ON A.ID = A.ID` which returns all the matches and then using that `WHERE A.date < B.date` to filter out the dates. This may mean you still return the whole table. Another way could be reversing the algorithm, but for now this works. Use (`) for coding.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try ROW_NUMBER () function order by timestamp descending and filtering out values having ROW_NUMBER 1 ;

Below query should fetch all records per id except the latest one

I tried below query in Oracle with a table having fields : id,user_id, record_order adn timestamp and it worked :

```
   select 
          <table_name_alias>.* 
        from 
        (
     select 
    id,
    user_id, 
        row_number() over (partition by id order by record_order desc) as record_number 
    from 
    <your_table_name>
 ) <table_name_alias> 
        where 
    record_number <>1;
```

If you are using Teradata DB, you can also try QUALIFY statement. I'm not sure if all DBs support this.

```
Select 
     table_name.* 
    from table_name 
    QUALIFY row_number() over (partition by id order by record_order desc) <>1;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Assuming "RANK" is a new table (rank appears to be a reserved word), I still am not able to get the above to work - the last line produces errors for me: "Expected AS, ID, or QUOTED_ID" (for WHERE) and "invalid column name r" (I used r in place of RANK)

Comment: @Johon this error is because the derived table needs an alias. And yes RANK is a reserved word. RowNum or R would better choices.

Comment: @Johonn :

Can u try below query, it did work for me in Oracle


 `select TABLE1.* from 
( select id,user_id, row_number() over (partition by id order 
by record_order desc) as record_number from TABLE_NAME ) TABLE1
where record_number  <>1;`

If you are using Teradata DB, you can also try QUALIFY statement. I'm not sure if all DBs support this.

`Select * from table_name
QUALIFY row_number() over (partition by id order 
by record_order desc) <>1;`

Comment: If you could edit that into your reply, it would be easier to read. I tried it out though and it returned no results. It's possible I'm using incorrect variables as I'm not really sure I understand what's going on here.

Comment: @Johonn : Sorry about the formatting. I have updated my answer . 
In my case record_order is version number, I guess you have to replace it with timestamp field. My query is fetching all records except the one which is having maximum record_order

First query  : It  partitions the data based on id ; sorts desending based on record_order field (you may have to sort it by timestamp) and assigns row number to each record in the partition starting from 1 .
The outer query will filter out all records having row number as 1 (the latest records for each id)